# How can I add condition in validator interface laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, required, laravel-validation

I see from here : https://github.com/andersao/laravel-validator

For example the code like this :

```
use \Prettus\Validator\LaravelValidator;

class PostValidator extends LaravelValidator {

    protected $rules = [
        ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE => [
            'title' => 'required',
            'text'  => 'min:3',
            'author'=> 'required'
        ],
        ValidatorInterface::RULE_UPDATE => [
            'title' => 'required'
        ]
   ];

}
```

I want to add condition if user is member(`if(Auth::id())`) then the field author not required

So the validator to be like this :

```
ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE => [
        'title' => 'required',
        'text'  => 'min:3'
],
```

The author required if the user is guest(no login)

Whether it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules) has a section on custom validators

Comment: From what i can see you still need to define custom logic, the package is just a building interface

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot execute instructions in a class properties, you can try to override the `create` method of your `Repository` instance, in order to modify the `$rules` parameter before the create actually takes place.

So in your `Repository` class, override the method `create`:

```
public function create(array $attributes)
{

    $oldRule = $this->rules[ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE]['author'];

    if(Auth::guest()){ // or use the preferred check
        unset($this->rules[ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE]['author']);
    }

    $this->makeValidator();
    $res = parent::create($attributes);

    $this->rules[ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE]['author'] = $oldRule;

    return $res;
}
```

**EDIT**

Another method could be specifying custom validation logic in your `PostValidator` as follows:

```
use \Prettus\Validator\LaravelValidator;

class PostValidator extends LaravelValidator {

    const RULE_CREATE_FOR_MEMBER = 'RULE_CREATE_FOR_MEMBER';

    protected $rules = [
        ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE => [
            'title' => 'required',
            'text'  => 'min:3',
            'author'=> 'required'
        ],
        self::RULE_CREATE_FOR_MEMBER => [
            'title' => 'required',
            'text'  => 'min:3'
        ],
        ValidatorInterface::RULE_UPDATE => [
            'title' => 'required'
        ]
   ];

   public function passes($action = null)
   {
       if($action == ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE && \Auth::id()) {
          $action = self::RULE_CREATE_FOR_MEMBER;
       }

       return parent::passes($action);
   }

}
```

But again, you need to override the standard behavior, it's up to you to decide which is the simplest solution for your needs.

Comment: It looks complicated. I think it seems to be able to add conditions in PostValidator class

Comment: It's not so complicated in my opinion. Another method would be setting a different validator for different user type (logged user or guest). The only problem is that when instantiating the repo on your controller i'm not so sure that the Auth object  would be instantiated on construction time of your controller

Comment: In both cases you have to override a standard funtionality of your validator. If you're going to override your validator class you need to override the `passes` method and provide your modified rules.